# Preview Problem Yoast SEO

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, previews

The problem is that the preview image/description that shows when sending the link to anyone , for example on whatsapp / messenger it shows the old logo / description
and i have already changed that from the settings of wordpress and also YOAST

so anyone might know what might be causing this / or maybe i might have forgotten something ?

Comment: Have a look at the og:image, og:description headers in the page you're linking to, and any similar ones for facebook twitter etc. - are they correct, or do they have the old versions you're seeing? Do you have cache layers on your website: could it be that you just need to invalidate the cache for these pages? (Or it's also possible that whatsapp and messenger are caching the old images and descriptions too from a previous lookup, but I'm not sure how that works)

Comment: If the issue is that the meta tags aren't updating though, then that's something you'll have to ask whoever is generating them (Yoast? Your theme?) directly for help.